# three20 TTNavigator demo code triggers a compiler warning

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, three20, ttnavigator

I am working through creating a similar project following the `TTNavigator` demo app and have fallen at the first hurdle.

I have duplicated the beginning section as show here:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
     TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
     navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;
     navigator.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:TTScreenBounds()] autorelease];
     TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
     [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
     [map from:@"tt://tabBar" toSharedViewController:[TabBarController class]];
     if (![navigator restoreViewControllers]) {
      [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://tabBar"]];
     }
}
```

And I have included the `TabBarController` but I get a compiler warning saying the controller may not respond to `setTabURLs`.

I have copy-pasted the controller and can't see where the problem is.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self setTabURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tt://menu/1",
                                             @"tt://menu/2",
                                             @"tt://menu/3",
                                             @"tt://menu/4",
                                             @"tt://menu/5",
                                             nil]];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Got it!

make sure this line is included in the Prefix.pch file :-)

```
 #import <Three20/Three20+Additions.h>
```

or include in source code!

Comment: #import what? <Three20/Three20.h>?

Answer (score 2):

the line the OP was referring to is:

`#import <Three20/Three20+Additions.h>`

(setTabUrls: is defined in a category on UIToolbarController)